# Pausing Matlab Script or Function on certain user event

Tags: matlab, user-controls, toggle

I know that there is the possibility of Matlab of pausing a Matlab function or script by using `input()` thus when I have a for-loop and want to pause it every iteration:

```
for i = 1:N
  reply = input(sprintf('Pausing in iteration %d! Continue with Enter!', i), 's');

  % Calculations
end
```

but how to get the following working: Usually it runs without pausing (as if the input() wouldn't be there) but when the user does something (perhaps press a key, a button, or something similar in matlab), the script/function does PAUSE each iteration until the the user does it again, thus something like this. E.g. let's say there is the possibility of matlab to toggle a variable whenh pressing a certain hotkey combination, e.h. Ctrl+Alt+A toggles the variable `myToggle` between 0 and 1 I could easily do:

```
for i = 1:N
  if(myToggle == 1)
    reply = input(sprintf('Pausing in iteration %d! Continue with Enter!', i), 's');
  end 

  % Calculations
end
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Just found ONE possible solution here: [Function to ask a MATLAB program to wait for an event before continuing execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652637/function-to-ask-a-matlab-program-to-wait-for-an-event-before-continuing-execution/3652697#3652697) I could create a file on the beginning of my function/script and pause on the next iteration when it doesn't exist anymore. But that would require the user to rename the file which isn't quite that 'comfortable'... Any other ideas? :)

Comment: are you looking to just pause the function and print some text? or do you need to input new data with each iteration?

Comment: Yeah just pause, the `input()` was just used to let the user press 'enter'-button to continue.

Comment: Relevant question: [matlab: stop and continue execution from debugger possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272541/matlab-stop-and-continue-execution-from-debugger-possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple GUI with a button; once pressed the execution halts on the next iteration.

```
function testGUI()
    doPause = false;
    figure('menu','none', 'Position',[400 400 150 30])
    hb = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','Pause', ...
        'Callback',@buttonCallback, 'Unit','Normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
    %drawnow

    while ishandle(hb)
        %# check if the user wants to pause
        if doPause
            pause()             %# pauses until user press any key

            %# reset
            doPause = false;
            if ishandle(hb), set(hb, 'Enable','on'), drawnow, end
        end

        %# Calculations
        disp(rand), pause(.1)

        %# keep the GUI responsive
        drawnow
    end

    %# callback function for the button
    function buttonCallback(hObj,ev)
        doPause = true;
        set(hObj, 'Enable','off')
    end
end
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply wanting to pause the script from running until the user presses return consider using the `pause` command in MATLAB